# ATM method program (possible logic or bracket errors)

Tags: java, methods

So, I have to make a program that acts as a basic ATM and I've encountered 2 problems:

- When I test the program for invalid passwords with a related account, the program is supposed to do a loop count that gives the user a max of 3 invalid attempts before it kicks the user out but instead it prints "Invalid password" 3 times and ends the program after the first wrong password. I believe this one is a bracketing error but I'm not actually sure myself

AND

- Whenever I run an operation like depositing money into the account, the program will display the new amount but it won't actually store the new value for the program. For example if I deposit $100 into account 1, it will say the new balance is $620.36, but when it loops back to the main menu and I check the new balance again and it reverts it back to the previous value, which it's not supposed to (tjis is where I think the logic error might be)

I was hoping for someone to be able to guide me in the right direction for either possible debugging solutions or a general solution of my error in coding.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ATM {
    public static Scanner kbd;

    private static final int MAXATTEMPTS = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello, user. This is an ATM.");
        System.out.println("Please enter account number");
        String acctNum = kbd.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter password");
        String pwd = kbd.next();
        int attemptNumber = 0;
        String res = checkID(acctNum, pwd);
        do{




            if (res.equals("error")){
                attemptNumber++;
                System.out.println("Invalid password, please try again.");

                if (attemptNumber == MAXATTEMPTS){
                    System.out.print("Maximum Login Attempts Reached.");
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            }
            else {
                double balance = Double.parseDouble(res);
                while(true){


                    int option = menu();

                    switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        displayBalance(balance);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        deposit(balance, balance);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        withdraw(balance, balance);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Thank you for banking with us, have a nice day!");
                        System.exit(0); 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (res.equals("error"));



        kbd.close();
    }


    /**
     * Determines if acctNum is a valid account number and pwd is the
     * correct password for the account.
     * @param acctNum The account number to be tested
     * @param pwd The possible password for the account
     * @return If the account information is valid, returns the account balance
     * as a string. If the account information is invalid, returns the string "error".
     */
    public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd)
    {
        String result = "error";

        // Strings a, b, and c contain the valid account numbers and passwords.
        // For each string, the account number is listed first, followed by
        // a space, followed by the password for the account, followed by a space,
        // followed by the current balance.
        String a = "44567-5 mypassword 520.36";
        String b = "1234567-6 anotherpassword 48.20";
        String c = "4321-0 betterpassword 96.74";

        String acctNum1, acctNum2, acctNum3, pwd1, pwd2, pwd3, bal1, bal2, bal3;
        acctNum1 = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "));
        acctNum2 = b.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "));
        acctNum3 = c.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "));
        pwd1 = a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1, a.lastIndexOf(" "));
        pwd2 = b.substring(b.indexOf(" ")+1, b.lastIndexOf(" "));
        pwd3 = c.substring(c.indexOf(" ")+1, c.lastIndexOf(" "));
        bal1 = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" " )+1);
        bal2 = b.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" " )+1);
        bal3 = c.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" " )+1);
        if (acctNum.equals(acctNum1) && pwd.equals(pwd1)){
            result = bal1;
        }
        if (acctNum.equals(acctNum2) && pwd.equals(pwd2)){
            result = bal2;
        }   
        if (acctNum.equals(acctNum3) && pwd.equals(pwd3)){
            result = bal3;
        }

        return result;
    }
    /**
     */
    public static int menu(){
        boolean invalidInput = true;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please select from the following options:");
            System.out.printf("1. Display Balance \n");
            System.out.printf("2. Deposit \n");
            System.out.printf("3. Withdraw \n");
            System.out.printf("4. Log Out \n");

            int choice = kbd.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1){
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                if (choice == 2){
                    return 2;
                }
                else{
                    if (choice == 3){
                        return 3;
                    }
                    if (choice == 4) {
                        return 4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        while(invalidInput);


        return 0;

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param accBalance given account balance for Account
     * @param depoAmnt amount going to be added to accBalance
     * @return double that will show updated balance
     */
    public static double deposit(double accBalance, double depoAmnt){
        System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit");
        depoAmnt = kbd.nextDouble();
        double newBalance = accBalance + depoAmnt;
        System.out.println("Your new balance is: " + newBalance);
        return newBalance;

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param accBalance amount of money in account
     * @return displays amount of money in account
     */
    public static void displayBalance(double accBalance){

        System.out.printf("\nYour current balancre is $%.2f\n", accBalance);


    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param accBalance given account balance for account
     * @param withdraw amount to be taken out of account
     * @return if withdraw !> accBalance, then it will be subtracted from it and resultant amount will be displayed
     */
    public static double withdraw(double accBalance, double withdraw){
        System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
        withdraw = kbd.nextDouble();
        if (accBalance < withdraw){
            System.out.printf("Cannot withdraw more than balance" + "\nYour current balance is: " + accBalance + "\n");
            return accBalance;
        }
        else {

            double newBalance = accBalance - withdraw;
            System.out.println("Your new balance is: " + newBalance);
            return newBalance;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt to solve the problem and then ask for help when you run into a difficulty, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Comment: You can split your question in 2 parts. But for the first one: you can't introduce 3 passwords if you read it only once: `String pwd = kbd.next();`. You need to add this in a loop.

Comment: consider using `String acctNum = kbd.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all your while loop will only execute if the result of the ID check is "error".  You need to change the condition of the loop to 'true' so it will run regardless, as this is the main event loop:

```
do {

    if (res.equals("error")){
        attemptNumber++;
        System.out.println("Invalid password, please try again.");

        if (attemptNumber == MAXATTEMPTS){
            System.out.print("Maximum Login Attempts Reached.");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
    else {
        double balance = Double.parseDouble(res);
        while(true){


            int option = menu();

            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                displayBalance(balance);
                break;
            case 2:
                deposit(balance, balance);
                break;
            case 3:
                withdraw(balance, balance);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Thank you for banking with us, have a nice day!");
                System.exit(0); 

            }
        }
    }
}
while (true);
```